# After a acquire a lease for a azure blob where do I find the release ID so I can release it?

Tags: azure, locking, azure-blob-storage

Following azure CLI using the document from [Azure CLI doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/lease?view=azure-cli-latest.), I can acquire the lease for my azure blob file.
However, to release the blob I need a release ID for my leased blob. Where can I get this ID from CLI?

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I get this ID from CLI?

Unfortunately you can't get the lease id after the fact. The lease id is not stored anywhere in the system. It is the responsibility of the lease acquirer to store the lease id.

Considering you don't have the lease id, thus you won't be able to release the lease. However what you can do is [`break the lease`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/lease?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-lease-break) which is same as releasing the lease and it does not require lease id.

```
az storage blob lease break --blob-name
                            --container-name
                            [--account-key]
                            [--account-name]
                            [--auth-mode {key, login}]
                            [--connection-string]
                            [--if-match]
                            [--if-modified-since]
                            [--if-none-match]
                            [--if-unmodified-since]
                            [--lease-break-period]
                            [--only-show-errors]
                            [--sas-token]
                            [--subscription]
                            [--timeout]
```

Comment: When you say it's lease acquirer responsibility to store the lease id. Where can I get it in order to store it?

Comment: When you acquire lease, you should get the lease id back.